# Administrator account vs elevated privileges: what's the difference?

Tags: windows, administrator, uac, privileges

What's the difference between an Administrator account and elevated privileges? What types of things Admin account grants and where do you need elevated privileges? (i.e. `run as administrator`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An Administrator account has the ability to "run as administrator", but no special privileges beyond that (assuming UAC is turned on). If you're running a non-administrator account, then you must provide the credentials to an Administrator account if you want to "run as administrator".

Comment: So basically standard user account is no more safe than administrator account? (with UAC turned on)

Comment: Well the standard account needs a password to make changes, external programs shouldn't be able to get a elevation token by themselves regardless, it is more about "who do you trust to make changes to your computer".

Comment: Strange that this question has an accepted answer without mentioning elevated rights, as asked  ...