# Windows 10 Administrator and Linux SuperUser

Tags: linux, windows-10, administrator, sudo, privileges

I understand that in Windows 10 Administrator is equivalent to the SuperUser in Linux. But I don't have the same power over my Machine as Linux gives with **su** or **sudo**

as an Example in Linux with **sudo**, commands like

```
rm -rf / --no-preserve-root
```

won't be a problem. But in windows I can't even delete **Window.old** folder even after being Administrator and taking **Full Control** from **Security**  and taking Ownership with

```
takeown /F Windows.old
```

also tried using **rimraf** tool from **npm**. Still won't completely delete the files.

So my Question is there any way in Windows 10 to take full control like **sudo** provides or its just that's how windows works.

Comment: Use the built-in Administrator in Windows

Comment: useful link : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/555910

Comment: you mean use the Administrator account rather then login in as user and taking Administrator Privileges?

Comment: To my understanding Its the same Privileges with different steps. as mention here: http://superuser.com/a/215124/201811

Comment: @Ahmad your understanding isn't correct, the built-in Administrator account, has a few differences between a user profile in the Administratoe user group.  Of course how you delete Windows.Old is well documented, you should use the clean-up tool, after you have elevated it's permission.

Comment: @Ahmad, Ramhound is correct, and as he said, you can use a third-party tool to clean up the Windows 7 old backup, try CCleaner, it has this feature.

Comment: Its not about cleaning up that folder. I'm talking about talking full control So even if I wanna delete everything I see in C drive I should have the permissions to do so.

Answer (score 3):

> I understand that in Windows 10 Administrator is equivalent to the SuperUser in Linux.

It's not.

First, administrators are constrained by UAC. If you're logged in as an administrator, but aren't granted full access, first make sure you're using an *elevated* Command Prompt window (e.g. by holding Ctrl+Shift while opening it, and getting the UAC prompt).

(Linux recently has been moving to a different model where apps perform actions through privileged services, rather than having to run the whole app as root.)

Second, administrators have different privileges. **root on Linux has CAP_FOWNER and CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE** (see [capabilities](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html)), allowing it to bypass all permission checks. (On other Unix-like systems, the bypass is granted to uid 0 in general.)

Administrators on Windows don't have the same; by default, they only have SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege active (similar to Linux CAP_CHOWN; see [privileges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530716(v=vs.85).aspx)). In other words, administrators can *reset* an object's security settings, but not *bypass* them.

To get a full security bypass on Windows, one would need to **enable SeBackupPrivilege and SeRestorePrivilege** for read & write access respectively (e.g. using [this tool](https://github.com/giuliano108/SeBackupPrivilege)). Administrators are *allowed* to use these privileges (after UAC elevation), but they aren't *active* by default – a process must 'enable' them first.

(You can see the available & enabled privileges in Process Explorer's "Security" tab, or in Process Hacker's "Token" tab. It's also possible to manually enable them e.g. for a running `cmd.exe` process.)

Comment: Remove-Item : Cannot remove item C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\SafeOS\SafeOS.Mount\windows\win
sxs\wow64_microsoft-windows-b..iagnostic.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.14342.1000_zh-c
n_b2ecdd1e524d0368\memtest.exe.mui: Access to the path is denied.
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-Item -Path "C:\`$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources" -Force

Comment: I used those dlls and got "PS C:\> Get-SeBackupPrivilege
SeBackupPrivilege is enabled"

but still access denied with Administrator Powershell.

Comment: also tried Copy still the same response: copy : The file cannot be accessed by the system.
At line:1 char:1
+ copy .\wgl4_boot.ttf D:\
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyI
   temCommand

Answer (score -1):

Windows administrator is closer to Linux Super-user than root.

In windows, the system is the closest equivalent to root.

Note that Windows 10 should automatically delete the Windows.old folder one month after you performed your upgrade.

Officially, it can be deleted with 'disk cleanup'. See the [exact step-by-step guide here](http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/delete-windows-old-folder)